# Failed to load static props with empty paths and fallback

Tags: next.js, internationalization, vercel, next-i18next

I have the following code on my Dynamic Routing page [id] that I am trying to use with next-i18next translations. However, it is throwing an error when being deployed on Vercel (working locally). I am trying to use the fallback function with an empty path array to somehow accept all possible paths(?). In my console I am getting a statuscode 500 GET-error and a "Failed to load static props"-error.

It is working when I specify a specific id within `getStaticPaths` and go to that matching path. However, I can't possibly specify thousands of ids for this to work. Shouldn't the fallback take care of this or how can I get past this?

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [], fallback: true
  }
}
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  return {
    props: {
      params: context.params,
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(context.locale, ["common"])),
    },
  }
}
```

Update:
This is the Vercel function log (xxxxx-values is some id's I removed)

```js
[GET] /_next/data/xxxxxxxxxxx-y/en/packages/490713.json
20:26:37:98
2022-02-28T19:26:39.300Z    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   ERROR   Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/var/task/public/locales/en'
    at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:1047:3)
    at getLocaleNamespaces (/var/task/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/config/createConfig.js:175:23)
    at /var/task/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/config/createConfig.js:181:20
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at getNamespaces (/var/task/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/config/createConfig.js:180:44)
    at createConfig (/var/task/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/config/createConfig.js:221:29)
    at _callee$ (/var/task/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/serverSideTranslations.js:199:53)
    at tryCatch (/var/task/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/var/task/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:294:22)
    at Generator.next (/var/task/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:119:21) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: '/var/task/public/locales/en',
  page: '/packages/[id]'
}
RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

Comment: Can you show us your `next-i18next.config.js` file too?

Answer (score 4):

This line was missing in my next-i18next-config

```js
localePath: path.resolve('./public/locales'),
```